# Different result for embedded append() call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table like this:

```
<table><tbody id="foo">
  <tr id="1"><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr id="2"><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
  <tr id="3"><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

When I apply a jQuery operation:

```
$('#foo').append($('#1'),$('#2'));
```

then I get the following (intended) result:

```
+-+-+
|e|f|
+-+-+
|a|b|
+-+-+
|c|d|
+-+-+
```

I want to embed the `append()` function in another function `myAppend()`, and I did this:

```
$.fn.myAppend = function(s){
  this.append(s);
  // something to be, which is irrelevant to this question
};
$('#foo').myAppend($('#1'),$('#2'));
```

The result was different from above, and I got this (unintended):

```
+-+-+
|c|d|
+-+-+
|e|f|
+-+-+
|a|b|
+-+-+
```

Why is the result different? How can I make `myAppend()` work in the same way as `append()`?

Comment: Have you put this function at the end of body tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the second parameter to `append`. Use `Function.prototype.apply` to invoke the `append` method with a variable number of `arguments`. To be able to chain method calls, return `this` from within the method.

```
$.fn.myAppend = function() {
  return this.append.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

[**JS Bin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/uJeZutu/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

ain't you need to pass both parameters i.e `$('#1')` and `$('#2')` to `myAppend` function..

by default function is taking first parameter i.e `$('#1')` and appending it only.

or you need to use a loop for each item you want to append

Answer (score 0):

Well you are passing two selectors in a functions parameters but you are using one there so instead you can try to pass it as an array in the custom `myAppend` function:

```
$('#foo').myAppend([$('#1'),$('#2')]);
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9z6F4/)

Comment: That makes the interface of `myAppend()` different from `append()`. As I clearly stated in the question, that is not what I want.